# How to temporarily disable some interface in pfSense?

Tags: networking, freebsd, pfsense

How to temporarily disable some interface in pfSense?

If I go to `Interfaces` and remove checkbox from `Enable interface`, then all settings disappear, making me think that I will be required to re-enter all interface configuration when re-enabling it.

I need to keep configuration, is it possible?

Comment: I am sure it's stored somewhere in a text file, which is standard in Unix world, so should be just a matter of copying the configuration aside. Grepping config files for a string that appears somewhere in your configuration is a sure way to find the proper config. Or maybe checking the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, so all should be fine.

pfSense uses ordinary XML for its config files, so you can copy and paste "chunks" between different saved configs very easily using any text editor if you are careful what you cut/paste.

HOW TO GET & RESTORE A CONFIG - The menu item "diagnostics->backup&restore" will get you a copy of your current config downloaded through your browser and also lets you save, modify and re-upload (restore) it any time you like. You can restore any config back to the same router, or to a "bare metal" or "clean install", or onto any other install of pfSense of the same version or later, and this will restore all your settings and data as well.

As a fallback or if paranoid, if you've backed up your config locally to a hard drive, you can always wipe and reinstall pfSense on the router if you hopelessly screw up. After first reboot, restore your old config and it should come back to being exactly as it was. One limitation - reinstall gets the latest versions of your packages off the net, so if those have changed then you might need to check your packages are installed as expected. But their config will be as you had it, when you've done that.

Alternatively, you can directly access the config in the GUI itself, although this needs some PHP basics. Go to "diagnostics->command prompt", and in the bottom section for PHP command line, type or paste this (including the final semi-colon):

```
print_r($config['interfaces']);
```

and click "execute".

Explanation - pfSense stores its current active configuration in an array called `$config`. The interfaces data is unsurprisingly held in a subarray of `$config` called `$config['interfaces']`. `print_r()` is a command to recursively print the contents of an array or variable in a human-readable format. So what this will do, is to dump the current "interfaces" section of the config to your screen, without the XML surrounding it.  You might find it useful to know. You can also `print_r($config);` to show the config, or similar for any other part of it, which can help if you need to check where things are mentioned or just for curiosity.

Two related points on this:

1. You *can* use command prompt to directly modify the config but I wouldn't recommend it unless you know what you're doing.  Subtle mistakes are easy and there's no safeguards for this method, so it's possible to bork the config, and then the router can have issues every time it tries to validate its cache of old saved configs, so its config recovery/restore handler throws an error, until you wipe and restore a valid config, or use the console/SSH to find and remove the error. Much safer to edit in a text editor where any errors will be picked up when you restore it, and allow you to retry without risk.
2. The console window also has a similar feature although you'll probably need some FreeBSD or at least Linux/*nix knowhow to get the config where it's needed, and to get it 'seen' by the OS.